# Conditional formatting 2 conditions met

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

Trying to get conditional formatting running through VBA code (since values change every day, also have a code to clean that deletes the Conditional formatting I did, non-VBA).

Want to highlight values on column P that are numeric > 0 and O4 > 0.

```
Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Cells("A1").Select
Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("P4").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=AND(ISNUMBER($P4), $P4>0, $O4>0)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 49407
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

The first line triggers the error:

> Run-time error '5'
>
> Invalid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would appear there is an issue with your first line, should be Range instead of Cells:

```
Sub Conditional_formatting_2_conditions_met()
    Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Activate
    Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("$P:$P").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=AND(ISNUMBER($P1), $P1>0, $O1>0)"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 49407
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Changed to "Range("A1")" and got error '1004' - Select method of range class failed

Comment: hmmm...instead try adding "Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Activate" before the line Sheets("RAW DATA FILE").Range("A1").Select

Also - Full code in answer

Comment: Changed as advised, no error but conditional formatting did not worked

Comment: hmmm...seems to be work for me, aftering keying in 1 into cells P4 and O4, P4 is formatted orange.

Comment: I think it is only applying formatting to cell P4, needs to be to column "P:P"

Comment: Ah got you now, i've updated the code to reflect this, change lines 5 and 6, formula should be: =AND(ISNUMBER($P1), $P1>0, $O1>0) and you'll need to select the whole of $P:$P

Answer (score 0):

You may use the loop throug all cells in range if You need to update more cells. You define the range at With .Range("P1:P10") line

```
Sub Conditional_formatting_2_conditions_met()

    Dim lRow    As Long
    Dim cel     As Range

    With Sheets("RAW DATA FILE")
        .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        With .Range("P1:P10")
            For Each cel In .Cells
                With cel
                    lRow = lRow + 1
                    With .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(ISNUMBER($P" & CStr(lRow) & "), $P" & CStr(lRow) & ">0, $O" & CStr(lRow) & ">0)")
                        .SetFirstPriority
                        .StopIfTrue = False
                        With .Interior
                            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                            .Color = 49407
                            .TintAndShade = 0
                        End With
                    End With
                End With
            Next cel
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hah I think you might've gone a little overboard with with with

Comment: Yea, could be easier with For Each cel In .Range("P1:P10") - 1x with statement less.